# How can I use the 'in' operator for $filter on Microsoft Graph Mail API?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365, odata, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to use the microsoft graph mail api to query for a small amount of emails using the in operator but cannot find an example.

This is how I am trying to use it:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=(from/emailAddress/address) in `'test@email.com, tester@address.com'`

In their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter), it says that you can use the in operator for $filter.

Comment: Instead of 'in', i used 'eq' and it works for me. You can try that out.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=from/emailAddress/address eq 'user@domain.com'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not opposing other answers, I am just leaving this snippet if anyone was looking for IN operator usage format:

```
$filter=displayName in ('group-1', 'group-2')
```

Full url example after encoding:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName%20in%20%28%27group-1%27%2C%20%27group-2%27%29
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28142407)

Comment: @gmds You are right, but for the time being, I can't find an example in the Microsoft documentation. The snippet I have provided is something I have written by hand that worked.