# Microsoft Graph client - retrieve more than 15 users?

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm using Microsoft Graph client and want to retrieve users based on a list of objectIds. So far I've managed to do it like this:

```cs
// Create filterstring based on objectId string list.
var filterString = string.Join(" or ", objectIds.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(objectId => $"id eq '{objectId}'"));

// Get users by filter
var users = await _graphServiceClient.Users.Request()
               .Select(x => new { x.UserPrincipalName, x.Id })
               .Filter(filterString)
               .GetAsync(ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But I've hit this error here:

```
Too many child clauses specified in search filter expression containing 'OR' operators: 22. Max allowed: 15.
```

Is there another way to only get a portion of users? Or do I need to "chunk" the list up in 15 each?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322392/how-can-i-use-the-in-operator-for-filter-on-microsoft-graph-mail-api ?

Comment: Alternatively, does nothing else link these users together? e.g. membership of a specific group, or some other attribute you could filter by, instead of a repetitive list of IDs?

Comment: The `IN` operator has a limit of 15 items as well.

Comment: @ADyson thanks, but no we only have the objectId to work with (we're integrating against another api) and need to "translate" that to something useful.

Comment: Try the "in" clause idea then, in the link I posted, see if it accepts more IDs that way rather than ORs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably split your query and send a BATCH request to the Graph API.
This will send only 1 request to the server, but allow you to query for more data at once.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp

This could look something like this: (untested code)

```cs
var objectIds = new string[0];
var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();
var requestList = new List<string>();

for (var i = 0; i < objectIds.Count(); i += 15)
{
    var batchObjectIds = objectIds.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Skip(i).Take(15);
    var filterString = string.Join(" or ", batchObjectIds.Select(objectId => $"id eq '{objectId}'"));

    var request = _graphServiceClient.Users.Request()
        .Select(x => new { x.UserPrincipalName, x.Id })
        .Filter(filterString);

    var requestId = batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(request);
    requestList.Add(requestId);
}

var batchResponse = await _graphServiceClient.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);

var allUsers = new List<User>();

foreach (var it in requestList)
{
    var users = await batchResponse.GetResponseByIdAsync<GraphServiceUsersCollectionResponse>(it);

    allUsers.AddRange(users.Value.CurrentPage);
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine except it had to be CollectionResponse instead of page (I've editted). I used a little different approach of grouping in 15, but otherwise almost the same. Thanks again :)

Comment: I'm still a little annoyed why we need to foreach the batchResponse. Isn't the point to only call the graph api once? I saw there was a ```GetResponsesAsync```, but this also requires a ```await responseHandler.HandleResponse``` foreach response retrieved.

Comment: I _think_ it's not each server request you're awaiting, but the receiving of the reply's body content. Not sure though :)

Comment: Yes sounds right, normally you also use response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() that can be awaited but not calling the server. I guess I could optimize it by doing the foreach in parallel :)