# Azure Graph Batch API Using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a way to do this http request using terraform?

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch  
Accept: application/json  
Content-Type: application/json  

{  
"requests": [  
    {  
        "id": "1",  
        "method": "GET",  
        "url": "/name?$filter=id in ('id1','id2'...'id20')"  
    },  
    {  
        "id": "2",  
        "method": "GET",  
        "url": "/name?$filter=id in ('id21'...)"  
    }  
  ]  
}
```

Terraform documentation https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http

I tried

```
data "http" "example_json" {
 url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch"

 method = "POST"

 request_headers = {
  content-type = "application/json"
  }

 request_body = jsonencode({  
        "id": "1",  
        "method": "GET",  
        "url": "/name?$filter=id in ('id1','id2'...'id20')"  
    },  
    {  
        "id": "2",  
        "method": "GET",  
        "url": "/name?$filter=id in ('id21'...)"  
    }  
  )

}
```

Getting error: Invalid Multi line string.

Terraform documentation:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/salrashid123/http-full/latest/docs/data-sources/http

I am looking for this solution using terraform mentioned in stack overflow link

[Microsoft Graph client - retrieve more than 15 users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66579149/microsoft-graph-client-retrieve-more-than-15-users)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the format with which the request body is given.

When I tried the request body in following format , I got error as `Function "jsonencode" expects only 1 argument(s).`

```
data "http" "graph_api_request" {
  url            = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch"
  method         = "POST"
  request_headers = {
    Content-Type = "application/json"
    ConsistencyLevel= "eventual"
    Authorization = "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1xxxxwT0dJOVlnTlEiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NixxxxWKh6bplw"
  }


   request_body = jsonencode({  
        "id": "1",  
        "method": "GET",  
        "url": "/users"  
    },  
    {  
        "id": "2",  
        "method": "GET",  
        "url": "/me"  
    }  
  )
 }  


output "graph_api_response" {
  value = "${jsondecode(data.http.graph_api_request.body)}"

  
}
```

[image]

The following code worked successfully :

**main.tf**

```
data "http" "graph_api_request" {
  url            = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch"
  method         = "POST"
  request_headers = {
    Content-Type = "application/json"
    ConsistencyLevel= "eventual"
    Authorization = "Bearer eyJ0eXxxxxxxxxw"
  }


  request_body   = jsonencode({
    requests = [
      {
        id          = "1"
        method      = "GET"
        url         = "/users"
      },
      {
        id          = "2"
        method      = "GET"
        url         = "/me"
      }
    ]
  })
}



output "graph_api_response" {
  value = "${jsondecode(data.http.graph_api_request.body)}"

  
}
```

provider.tf:

```
terraform {
   
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source  = "azure/azapi"
      version = "=1.2.0"
    }

    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.2"
    }


http   =  {
  source ="hashicorp/http"
    }

 }
```

result:

[image]

[image]